# jQuery .append() is altering page layout in a wrong way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a bit of a problem - I'm trying to do this:

```
$('#content').append('<div class="square"><h2>'+item.name+'</h2><h3>'+item.comment+'</h3></div>');
```

and it's displaying the content like this: [image: actual result]

...but I want it to display the content like this: [image] 
...which it does do if I remove the javascript variables from the append and replace it with just any old text.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Here's a fuller version of the code if necessary:

```
$.ajax({ 
      url: 'yourcurations.php', 
      data: '', 
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $('#content').append('<div class="square"><h2>'+item.name+'</h2><h3>'+item.comment+'</h3></div>');
        })
      }
});
```

### CSS

```
.square {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-right:50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: black;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: -15px;
    color: gray;
}
```

HTML

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yG1UWja.png?1]

Many thanks

Comment: This is more than likely a CSS problem. you should post your CSS code.

Comment: How about a little CSS code?

Comment: Ah of course, I'll just post it

Comment: do you have any styles for your h2 or h3 element?

Comment: Is the structure of the HTML as expected when you do View source in the browser?

Comment: @Stian yeah it's exactly as it should be

Comment: Please post the generated HTML.

Comment: Try adding `width: 150px;` to `h2, h3`. If this doesn't work you may have to post a jsFiddle so I can debug.

Comment: @Taimur do this and see if works: `#content{display:block;}` this will do the job you need.

Comment: Neither of those worked I'm afraid :( here is a jsfiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/cvxTP/ , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really understand why it works, but if you put
`vertical-align: top;`

in the `.square` class, it seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You see the unwanted result because the heading gets wrapped in the box which pushes the next element down a bit. You can probably fix it by setting a fixed height on the heading elements.